# Access data via redux for SectionList

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux, react-native-sectionlist

I have a initial state as below in reducer

```
const initialState = {
    medicationschedule: [
        {
            date: '2019-08-27',
            medications: [
                {
                    title: '8.00 AM', 
                    data: [
                        {name:'item1', isTaken: 1,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}, 
                        {name:'item2', isTaken: 4,mg: '2000 mg',capsules:'teaspoon'}
                ]},
                {
                    title: '12.03 PM', 
                    data: [
                        {name:'item3', isTaken: 2,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}, 
                        {name:'item4', isTaken: 1,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}
                ]},
                {
                    title: '3.30 PM', 
                    data: [
                        {name:'item1', isTaken: 3,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}
                ]},
            ]
        }
    ],
    medication: [
        {
            title: '8.00 AM', 
            data: [
                {name:'item1', isTaken: 1,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}, 
                {name:'item2', isTaken: 4,mg: '2000 mg',capsules:'teaspoon'}
        ]},
        {
            title: '12.03 PM', 
            data: [
                {name:'item3', isTaken: 2,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}, 
                {name:'item4', isTaken: 1,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}
        ]},
        {
            title: '3.30 PM', 
            data: [
                {name:'item1', isTaken: 3,mg: '500 mg',capsules:'capsule'}
        ]},
    ]
};
```

I have my class as below for the React Native `SectionList`.

```
class HomeScreen extends Component {

    state = { 
        selectedDate: Date(),
        isModalVisible: false,
     };


    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={styles.containter}>



                <SectionList
                    renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <MedicineRow showTitle={0}  key={index} setWidth='80%' title={item.name} mg={item.mg} capsules={item.capsules} onPress={() => this.medicineRowTapped(item.name)} medstatus={item.isTaken}/>}
                    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
                    renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
                       <SectionTitle showTitle={true} title={title}/>
                    )}
                    sections={ 
                        this.props.filteredMedications
                    }
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
                />
            </SafeAreaView>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        filteredMedications : state.medication
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen)
```

The list succesfully loads if I access the medication as given in the `mapStateToProps`. But if I attempt to filter the data inside `medictionschedule` based on the date then the sectionlist doesn't load anything in the screen.

Filtering in an external function also not helping here as shown below.

```
medicineForTheDate = () => {
    this.props.filteredMedications.filter((schedule) => {
        if (schedule.date === '2019-08-27') {
            return schedule.medications
        }
    })
}
```

then inside the `SectionList` I would call `this.medicineForTheDate()`

```
<SectionList
    renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <MedicineRow showTitle={0}  key={index} setWidth='80%' title={item.name} mg={item.mg} capsules={item.capsules} onPress={() => this.medicineRowTapped(item.name)} medstatus={item.isTaken}/>}
    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
    renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
       <SectionTitle showTitle={true} title={title}/>
    )}
    sections={ 
        this.medicineForTheDate()
    }
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
/>
```

I also tried filtering inside the `mapsStateToProps` but that also didn't help.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        filteredMedications : state.medicationschedule.filter((schedule)=>{ schedule.date === '2019-08-27' })
    }
}
```

and then...

```
<SectionList
                    renderItem={({item, index, section}) => <MedicineRow showTitle={0}  key={index} setWidth='80%' title={item.name} mg={item.mg} capsules={item.capsules} onPress={() => this.medicineRowTapped(item.name)} medstatus={item.isTaken}/>}
                    stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}
                    renderSectionHeader={({section: {title}}) => (
                       <SectionTitle showTitle={true} title={title}/>
                    )}
                    sections={ 
                        this.props.filteredMedications.medications
                    }
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
                />
```

How do I go about filtering data in this context?

Comment: Did you check the filter is working correctly?

Comment: @JebinBenny oh my god. Thanks for saving my day. I found the issue after checking the filter.

Comment: If you still have issue, please add extraData props to your section list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a start, the `filter` method expects a function, which takes in a parameter (the item inside the array) and returns a true (if the item should be in the filtered array) or a false (if the item should NOT be in the filtered array)

For example:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const evenNumbersOnly = arr.filter((item) => {
  if (item % 2 === 0) {
    // Even (Want it in the list
    return true;
  } else {
    // Odd (Don't want it in the list
    return false;
  }
});

// evenNumbersOnly will now be [2, 4]
```

Try changing your `filter` method and see if the filtered array is what you are expecting. From there, I believe you will be able to continue debugging if it still does not show expected results.

Answer (score 1):

Try this!

```js
medicineForTheDate() {
 let filteredValue = this.props.filteredMedications.filter((schedule) => {
            if (schedule.date === '2019-08-27') {
                return schedule.medications
            }
           });
  return filteredValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are close but you have some minor errors in each of your approaches.

In approach 1 with the external method you are not returning a value from the method and `filter` is not working like you expect. The `filter` method on an array will return another array only containing the elements of the original array where the filter clause returns a truthy value. So in your example even though you return `schedule.medications` you are still ending up with an array with the original data. The most similar code to your intention I believe is this:

```
medicineForTheDate = () => {
    const matchingMedications = this.props.filteredMedications.filter((schedule) => {
        return schedule.date === '2019-08-27'; // filter if dates are equal
    })
    if (matchingMedications.length) { // if we have a result
        return matchingMedications[0].medications;
    }
    // decide about a default value if there is no match
}
```

That said I think a for loop is more clear:

```
medicineForTheDate = () => {
    const {filteredMedications} = this.props;
    for (let i=0; i < filteredMedications.length; i++) {
      const schedule = filteredMedications[i];
      if (schedule.date === '2019-08-27') {
         return schedule.medications
      }
    }
    // decide if you want to return a different value if no match is found
}
```

For the second case you have similar errors - using filter incorrectly and not actually returning a value from filter. Again something like

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        filteredMedications : state.medicationschedule.filter((schedule)=>{ return schedule.date === '2019-08-27' })[0]
    }
}
```

will work as long as you account for `filteredMedications` being undefined in your component in that case if there is no match for the date.